# QTreeWidget header column merging

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtablewidget, qtreewidget

I've a `QTreeWidget`. I need to create the following system of columns.

| ▼ Record N1 |
| --- |

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ |
| ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ |

| ▼ Record N2 |
| --- |

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ |
| ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ |

But i can't understand how to merge columns above subcolumns to achieve one line with **Record N1, Record N2** etc. I thought to add a table widget in every **Record** instead of subitems like **Col1, Col2** etc. But i don't want to overweight the code with creating this bundle. Is it possible to achieve the same result but with treewidget only?

The main point: create a `QTreeWidget` with one column with lot of subcolumns, like table, in this main column.
In addition, i want to use literally `QTreeWidget` because it's expandable raws.

Comment: The only way would do to create "child" tree widgets, and add them with [`setItemWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#setItemWidget). Otherwise, create custom widgets as top level items, and add actual tree widgets as "child items", then use that custom top level item to toggle their visibility.

Comment: You already know the answer - the ```QTreeWidget``` doesn't support placing a new header for each row.

Comment: I decided to append a TreeWidget with child-TableWidget into ScrollArea

Comment: Then, why not answer your own question?